# Rails send model update email when a submodel is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, actionmailer

So I have two models:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :model_b
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :model_a
end
```

When ModelA is created, the controller sends an email:

```
if @model_aA.save
      Emailer.delay.new_model_a(@model_a.id)
```

And if it's edited:

```
if @model_a.update(model_a_params)
        Emailer.delay.edit_model_a(@model_a.id)
```

However, if the edit is the **creation of a modelB object**, the edit email isn't sent. It sends if a modelB owned by modelA is edited, but not if it is created.

How would I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use model callbacks for that. You don't need to call the mailer methods on the controller but in an after_create/after_save/after_update hook for example.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { |instance| Emailer.delay.new_model_a(instance.id) }
  after_update { |instance| Emailer.delay.edit_model_a(instance.id) }
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create { |instance| Emailer.delay.new_model_b(instance.id) }
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but what if I create 2 different modelB? I still only want to send one email, to avoid spam and such.

Comment: That would be a little more complicated as the modelb's don't know from each other in the after_create. Maybe you could override `model_bs_attributes` in ModelA to set an virtual attribute (attr_accessor) if called and send your mail in the after_update/after_save hook if that attribute is set.

Comment: or maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814878/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-callbacks